# Pixabay License terms

Tags: legal

Pixabay states in their licence terms that

> What is not allowed?
>
> This section only applies to image users and not to the appropriate
>   image authors.
>
> ✕ Don't redistribute or sell someone else's Pixabay images or videos
>   on other stock or wallpaper platforms.
>
> ✕ **Don't sell unaltered copies
>   of an image. e.g. sell an exact copy of a stock photo as a poster,
>   print or on a physical product.**
>
> ✕ Don't portray identifiable people in
>   a bad light or in a way that is offensive.
>
> ✕ Don't use images with
>   identifiable brands to create a misleading association with a product
>   or service.

How should I interpret the bold part? I understand that selling a product where the image is the substance of the product (the product is blank/worthless without it), like a poster is not allowed (no one would buy a blank poster), but what if the image is complimentary, ie. in a book where the product itself doesn't rely on containing the image to be sold. The product would cost the same regardless of containing the image.

Further, does "Don't sell unaltered copies" mean that altered ones can be sold? How much would it have to be altered?

It is obvious to me that no one except their legal team could answer this exactly, therefore I am interested in experienced opinions. I think their wording is simple, but a little vague.

Comment: About selling unaltered copies: you'd need to consult with a lawyer or the stock image legal department. If a legal question can only be answered by a lawyer then it's off-topic here.

Comment: related https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79796/how-to-manipulate-a-photograph-so-that-it-becomes-original-artwork

Answer (score 1):

> Don't sell unaltered copies of an image. e.g. sell an exact copy of a stock photo as a poster, print or on a physical product.

You can sell posters where you use a stock photo, as long as the poster is not *just the photo* (aka reselling the image). You cannot just frame it and sell it, nor print a mug and sell it, unless the stock photo is edited somehow.

How much is enough? that is a question for a lawyer. Check [this other similar question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/87866/at-what-point-can-an-image-be-considered-redrawn) and [this other one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79796/how-to-manipulate-a-photograph-so-that-it-becomes-original-artwork).